# How to compute intraclass standard deviation without loops in matlab?

Tags: matlab, standard-deviation

I have a data set with n samples d features represented by a n*d matrix. The corresponding label is a n*1 vector. How can I compute each intraclass standard deviation without loops in matlab?

For example:

Samples

```
 5     1     1     1     4
 5     2     5     3     1
 1     3     5     5     5
 5     5     3     4     5
 4     5     5     5     4
```

Label:

```
2
1
1
2
2
```

How can I compute class 1 and class 2's standard deviation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `accumarray`, you can calculate the standard deviations like this:

```
stdev = cell2mat(accumarray(label,(1:length(label))',[],@(x){std(samples(x,:))}));
```

If you have the Statistics toolbox, you can use `grpstats` instead:

```
stdev = grpstats(samples,label,'std')
```

Comment: +1: Tell me, is there anything you **can't** do with `accumarray`? :)